# B-tree and BST used-case

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, b-tree

I have read that B-tree was primarily intended for secondary storage look-ups owing to minimized disk seeks.

But, considering the locality of reference it provides - and the consequent reduced possibility of cache misses; wouldn't it be a preferred candidate for primary (in-memory) look-ups too?
Why would I ever use a BST over this?

Answer (score 0):

If by B-tree you mean a balanced search tree as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), locality of memory is not its only purpose, but also favourable complexity for data access. In total, a B-tree might be preferrable also for in-memory data structures, but might be harder to implement.

Comment: So is it all about implementation ease?I know there may not be a definite answer ,but I wanted to be aware of the different factors that should be kept in purview.